# Mysql get result in single query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

How to find out results in single query

I have the following 2 tables:

[image]

[image]

`master_data_values` table has foreign key of `master_data` table.

By combining 2 tables I want "**Value**" (from master_data_value) to be considered depending on 3 params - account_id, specility_id, user_id for each "**key**"(from master_data table).

Now i have following priority

1.user_id

2.account_id

3.specility_id 
.

I will have single query to which i will send above 3 params as per request.

Now suppose:

if request params do not match anything then it should return value with all NULL's

example results

I am querying with user_id= 67 and specility_id = 55 and account_id = 4

then my result which will return all master_data_values like below
[image]

now here for key **GET_DATA** i got value **YES** and for **PUT_DATA** got value **NO**. here for GET_DATA there was no matching criteria for user_id, account_id, specility_id for values provided by me . so it took value from master_data_values table which has all set to null. while for **PUT_DATA** it matched to user_id so it took value "**NO**"

2nd example

Suppose my query params are account_id = 1 , specility_id = 2 and user_id = null

then it should give preference to account_id and result should look like 
[image]

here for GET_DATA i got value YES. and for PUT_DATA got value YES

here there were 2 matching criteria's for GET_DATA i.e account_id and specility_id. but as per preference it took value which was assigned to account_id and it was "YES".

​Note - ​ I am using mysql 5.7

script for reference to create table and sample data Please execute them in order .

```
CREATE DATABASE `test_schema` ;

​CREATE TABLE `test_schema`.`master_data` (
  `master_data_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`master_data_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test_schema`.`master_data` (`key`) VALUES ('GET_DATA');
INSERT INTO `test_schema`.`master_data` (`key`) VALUES ('PUT_DATA');

CREATE TABLE `test_schema`.`master_data_values` (
  `master_data_value_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `master_data_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `account_id` INT(11) NULL,
  `specility_id` INT(11) NULL,
  `user_id` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`master_data_value_id`),
  INDEX `fk_master_data_values_1_idx` (`master_data_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_master_data_values_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`master_data_id`)
    REFERENCES `test_schema`.`master_data` (`master_data_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

INSERT INTO `test_schema`.`master_data_values` (`master_data_id`, `value`, `account_id`) VALUES ('1', 'YES', '1');
INSERT INTO `test_schema`.`master_data_values` (`master_data_id`, `value`, `specility_id`) VALUES ('1', 'NO', '2');
INSERT INTO `test_schema`.`master_data_values` (`master_data_id`, `value`) VALUES ('1', 'YES');
INSERT INTO `test_schema`.`master_data_values` (`master_data_id`, `value`) VALUES ('2', 'YES');
INSERT INTO `test_schema`.`master_data_values` (`master_data_id`, `value`, `user_id`) VALUES ('2', 'NO', '67');
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry - thanks for response!!   i have given "example results" in questions u can refer expected behaviour with example params

Comment: It's just a suggestion. Obviously, you're competely at liberty to disregard it.

Comment: @Strawberry I have added  script in question  to replicate the problem. Please refer them .

Comment: @Strawberry i have updated the question with all possible sample data and description to identify the problem , Please help me out